# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches action and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I couldn't find a solution in the other relative questions, so I'm asking my own.

The problem is pretty straightforward. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Failure/Error: get 'api/v2/special_keys#show'
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"api/v2/special_keys#show", :controller=>"api/v2/special_keys"}
```

This is my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :special_keys, only: [] do
  collection do
    get '', to: 'special_keys#show'
  end
end
```

This is the output from `rake routes`:

```
GET /api/v2/special_keys(.:format) api/v2/special_keys#show {:format=>"json"}
```

And my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Api::V2::SpecialKeysController do
  describe 'GET #show' do
    it 'gets the policy and signature' do
      get '/api/v2/special_keys'

      expect(response.status).to eql 200
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How does your controller code look like?
Could it be that you only allow json format?

Comment: Yes, I indeed allow only json format.

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite your test as:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Api::V2::SpecialKeysController do
  describe 'GET #show' do
    it 'gets the policy and signature' do
      get '/api/v2/special_keys', {format: :json}

      expect(response.status).to eql 200
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So that helped me figure this out. First thing I did is I made the GET request in the spec to `:show`. Second thing I did is I signed in using `before`, otherwise 401 error was returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
resource :special_keys, only: [:show]
```

The singular tells the app, that there is only one. So it will only generate a `show` action that needs no id and no `index`action at all.

Comment: At first, I tried with `resources :special_keys, only: [:show]` but that ended up with having to add an ID to the request URL, which I didn't need (e.g. `/api/v2/special_keys/1`. Your code leaves me with this error: `uninitialized constant Api::V2::SpecialKeysController`

Comment: Do you have a controller-file `special_keys_controller.rb` defining `Api::V2::SpecialKeysController` in `app/controller/api/v2` ?

Comment: No, because I don't need one.

Comment: **Controllers** are the 'thing' that contain the actions that routes point to. So be assured: You **do need** one. Above is the location that rails will look for it. If it's somewhere else you have to tell Rails where.